# Disable popify in shiny after once mouse over away from icon

Tags: r, shiny

in the below application, when the user clicks on the i icon, only then it the box is displayed. This is fine. But the box disappears only when the user clicks again on i icon. Can we disable this. Like it should appear when the user clicks on i icon, but should disappear when the mouse moves away?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("pop")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$pop <- renderUI({
    h4(style="margin-top:10px;display:initial;","topic",popify(el = icon(name = "info-circle", lib = "font-awesome"), title = "",
                                                               content = paste0("aims"
                                                               ),placement="right",trigger = "click",options = list(container = "body")))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is it important for you that the button is clicked ? if no, you can use `shinyBS::bsTooltip()` to show info only when the mouse is over the button.

Comment: Yes. it is important. Because when there is any link inside box, we cannot click as it disappears. You got it?:)

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If you want it to disappear when you move mouse away from the icon, then when you move your mouse into the popover to click the link, you have left the icon already. It means the popover should be disappeared. Then, how do you click the link inside the popover?